# How to save text from a web page

Tags: ios8

I want to build an app that will save selected text from a website to the app, like Pocket or Evernote. Is there a method or function within Swift that will allow me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you done @mhs5819?

Comment: I'm still at the prototype stage.